# What does these number in random no. generator do?

Tags: python, math, random

Basically i understand the program but not the math/numbers used here.

```
import random

def r_int():
  x = int(abs(10 * random.random() % 20))
  return x
```

I figured out this is equivalent to `random.randint(0,9)`. What does the `%` and `20` do here?

Comment: `%` is the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

Comment: It limits the random numbers to be between 0 and 19. Look up the modulo operator

Comment: It does nothing since `10 * random.random()` cannot be greater than 10.

Comment: Whoever wrote that code doesn't know what they're doing... unless you made a mistake or two copying it here.

Answer (score 4):

`%` is the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations); it returns the *remainder* of a division operation on the first operand.

`% 20` means: return the remainder of the first operand divided by 20; that's always a number in the range [0.0, 20.0) (0 included, 20 is not).

This makes the `abs()` call entirely redundant, because the result is always positive. Not that the modulo operator has any point either, because `10 * random.random()` is always a floating point number in the range [0.0, 10.0) (so lower than 10). Any number lower that 20.0, modulus 20, is that same number.

They could just have used `random.randrange(10)` and avoided all this confusion.